# Using external document parameter in XQuery invoked via Camel

Tags: xquery, apache-camel

I am passing DOM object as parameter to Xquery in Camel.

Below is the Xquery code, written to access the parameter:

```
declare variable $dom_param as document-node() external;
declare variable $someVariable := $dom_param/h1/text();
```

On running above, I get following error:

```
XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #...T as document(dom_param#:
Expected type name in SequenceType, found <function>(
Error on line 7 column 36
XPST0003 XQuery syntax error near #... variable $someVariable := /{$#:
expected ";", found "{"
```

Any idea on how can this be solved?

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the camel implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Passing document nodes from outside is likely to be tricky, in the usual case, because it requires the XQuery engine and the environment to agree on so much.  If the implementations you're using do support it, check the documentation very carefully and start by running the examples given in the documentation itself.

One possible work-around is to pass in not a document node but a string containing the URI of the document, and then use the fn:doc() function to read it.  If your DOM object is being constructed dynamically that may be a challenge.